# a characterisation of proper maps via ultrafilters

Tags: gn.general-topology

Let $B$ be a topological space. 
Call a subset $A\subset B$ *ultrafilter-like* iff $A$ is dense in $B$ and
each decomposition $A=A_1\cup A_2$, 
into the union of two open subsets extends to a decomposition of
$B=B_1\cup B_2$, $A_1\subset B_1$ and $A_2\subset B_2$ into the union of two open subsets $B_1$ and $B_2$.

Is the following true? Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a proper map
and $A\subset B$ is ultrafilter-like.
For any  $g:A\rightarrow X$ and $h:B\rightarrow Y$  such that
$f(g(a))=h(a)$ for each $a\in A$, there is a map $g':B\rightarrow X$
extending $g$ such that $f(g'(b))=h(b)$ for each $b\in B$.

Is this true if $Y$ is a point (and thus $X$ is an arbitrary 
quasi-compact space).

This is true provided $B=A\cup \{\omega\}$
where $\omega$ is closed. If  $A$ is discrete, then the neighbourhoods of $\omega$
define an ultrafilter on $A$ and the property becomes
the definition of a proper map via ultrafilters (see Bourbaki, General Topology, I\S10.2, Theorem I).
 If $A$ is not necessarily discrete, then there is an ultrafilter $F$ on $A$
such that the neighbourhoods of $\omega$ are $F$-big,
and the same arguments works. (To fix the terminology: by a proper map
I mean a closed map such that the preimage of any point is quasi-compact).

Comment: How about the following (possible) counterexample: Let $a,b$ be two distinct free ultrafilters in $X=\beta\omega$, $Y=X/\{a,b\}$ be the quotient space and $q:X\to Y$ be the quotient map. Let $B=Y$ and $A=\beta B\setminus \{q(a),q(b)\}$ and $f:A\to X\setminus\{a,b\}$, $g:B\to Y$ be the identity maps. It seems that no map $h$ with the required properties exists. Is it Ok?

Comment: I do not understand your notation: which is the ultralifter-like map and which is the proper map ? $\beta\omega\rightarrow\beta\omega/\{a,b\}$ is the proper map and $\beta B\setminus\{q(a),q(b)\} \rightarrow \beta\omega/\{a,b\}$ is the ultrafilter-like map ? but the latter is not a subset, is it?

Comment: $\beta\omega\to\beta/\{a,b\}$ is the proper map. $\beta B\setminus\{q(a),q(b)\}$ should be $\beta\omega\setminus\{q(a),q(b)\}$. Sorry for this misprint.

Comment: so is it $\beta\omega\rightarrow \beta\omega / \{a,b\}$ and $\beta\omega\setminus \{q(a),q(b)\} \rightarrow \beta\omega/ \{a,b\}$ ? (there is another misprint in the first map, nothing follows $\beta$) I do not see it, as $q(a),q(b)\in Y$ are elements of the quotient..

Comment: And what is wrong with $q(a),q(b)\in Y$?

Comment: I am sorry for delay. what is the topology on the domain of the ultrafilter-like map? it is not the induced topology? I require that the topology on subset A is induced from B

Comment: The topology on the domain $X$ is the subspace topology inherited from $\beta\omega$. The qotient map $q:\beta\omega\to Y$ restricted to $X=\beta\omega\setminus\{a,b\}$ is a topological embedding of $X$ into $Y=B$ (because of the properness of $q$. By the way, in my first comment I made a mistake defining $q$ as the qutient map from $X$. It should be the quotient map from $\beta\omega$.

Comment: I am a bit lost in notation: above it said $X=\beta\omega$... Let me try to start from scratch. We have two free ultrafilters $a,b \in\beta\omega$, $a\neq b$.

Comment: I am a bit lost in notation: above it said $X=\beta\omega$... Let me try to start from scratch. We have two free ultrafilters $a,b \in\beta\omega$, $a\neq b$. the proper map is $\beta\omega\rightarrow \beta\omega/\{a,b\}$. the ultrafilter-like map is $\beta\omega\setminus\{a,b\}\rightarrow \beta\omega$. Is this correct?

Comment: In my example the embedding $A\subset B$ is not ultrafilter-like. So, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C$ be a connected Tychonoff space and $a,b\in \beta C\setminus C$ be two distinct points. Let $X=\beta C$, $Y=X/\{a,b\}$ be the quotient space and $f:X\to Y$ be the quotient map. It is clear that $f$ is perfect and hence proper.

Let $B=Y$, $A=B\setminus \{q(a)\}$, $h:B\to Y$ be the identity map, $g=q^{-1}|A:A\to X\setminus\{a,b\}\subset X$ be the homeomorphism of $A=Y\setminus\{q(a)\}$ onto $X\setminus\{a,b\}$. It is easy to see that $f\circ g=h|A$. On the other hand, it can be shown that $g$ admits no continuous extension to a map $g':B\to X$ such that $f\circ g'=h$.

The space $g(A)$ is connected sinse it contains a dense connected subspace $C$. Then the space $A$ is connected as well (being homeomorphic to $g(A)$). The connectedness of $A$ implies that $A$ is ultrafilter-like in $B$ (being connected the space $A$ admits no non-trivial partitions into two open sets).

So, to get a sensible answer, we should assume that the space $A$ is disconnected, or better (strongly) zero-dimensional. In this case there is a hope for the positove answer since ultrafilter-likenes of $A$ in $B$ should imply that the identity embedding $A\to\beta A$ extends to an embedding of $B$ into $\beta(A)$.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, this appears an interesting counterexample, though not exactly to what I was asking (there was no requirement that $A=A_1\cup A_2$ where $A_1$ and $A_2$ are disjoint).